# Menu item with update text (title) in real time

Tags: 7

I have a menu where one of the items (menu links) is a link to a view where I can see all comments that I have to moderate. Which I need is (if it is possible) to have the title of this link that change in realtime (or every time I load a page/node).

Think to my situation where I don't know how many comments I need to moderate so in this moment every X minutes I reload the page with all comments that I have to moderate. But this is frustating. So my necessity is to have a menu item like "Comments to moderate: FOO" where FOO is a number (from 0 to infinite) that I can calculate in realtime at every page load or every BAR minutes.

M.

Comment: do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved a similar problem:

You need implement the `hook_menu()` and use the '`title callback`'

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['perfil-usuario'] = array(
        'title' => 'perfil',
        'description' => t('User Profile'),
        'title callback' => 'change_title_profile_link',
        'page callback' => 'go_to_profile',
        'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'weight' => 100,
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        'options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => array('perfil-usuario'))),
        ); 

    return $items;
}
```

In this function you can change the link title

```
function change_title_profile_link() {
    return rand();
}
```

Here you can redirect to the desire url, if the url change you can implement this function

```
function go_to_profile() {
}
```